# Analyzing the sequence of functions: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(x-1)^n}{\ln(1+\frac 1n)5^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(x-1)^n}{\ln(1+\frac 1n)5^{n+1}}$$

I'm having some difficulties with that sequence, I can't seem to find the right algebraic trick to get rid of the $\infty\cdot0$ form (or maybe there's anothe way?).

My suspicion is that the function converges to $0$ within the $(-4,6)$ interval because that's where $\left|{\frac{x-1}{5}} \right|\lt 1$, but I cannot show it due to the $\frac {1}{\ln(1+ \frac 1n)}$ bit being divergent.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is good, but you didn't prove anything ! Set $$u_{n}=\frac{(x-1)^n}{5^{n+1}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}.$$
Then $$\left|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right|=\left|\frac{x-1}{5}\right|\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }\left|\frac{x-1}{5}\right|.$$
Using d'Alembert criterion allow to conclude when $\left|\frac{x-1}{5} \right|\neq 1$. When It's equal to $1$, compute manually the limit (the result is quite obvious).

Comment: I think the logarithm fraction should be switched, the $\ln(1+\frac 1n)$ should go on top.
Is d'Alambert criterion the "ratio test"? I thought it worked only for series.
Anyway the logarithm fraction is equal to $1$ at infinity so, if d'Alembert criterion works like the ratio test, the sequence converges when $\left| \frac {x-1}{5} \right|$ is less then $1$. Correct?

Comment: @Simone: I corrected it. Thank you. Yes, it converges (to $0$) when $\left|\frac{x-1}{5}\right|<1$. But when it's equal to 1 you can't say anything using this test.

Comment: No problem. But we just showed that it converges on that interval, now how do we show that it converges to $0$? Is it because $\frac {(x-1)^n}{5^n}$ convergs to $0$ there and so the whole sequence has to go there?

Comment: @Simone: It's d'Alembert criterion ! If $|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}|\to \rho <1$ then $(u_n)$ converges to $0$.

Comment: ah! I didn't know that! Thank you! @Surb. To conclude I'd say that at $x=6$ the sequence diverges.

Comment: Not really... if $x=6$ it will diverges to $+\infty $ and if $x=-4$ it will diverges strongly (i.e. you can find a subsequence that goes to $+\infty $ and a subsequence that goes to $-\infty $.)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that:

$\frac{(x-1)^n}{\ln(1+\frac 1n)5^{n+1}} = \frac{\left(\frac{x-1}{5}\right)^n}{5 \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})} \sim \frac{n}{5}\left(\frac{x-1}{5}\right)^n $, $n \to \infty$

So limit exist iff exist limit of $\frac{n}{5}\left(\frac{x-1}{5}\right)^n$.

If $x \in (-6, 4)$:

$\frac{n}{5}\left(\frac{x-1}{5}\right)^n \to 0$, $n \to \infty$

Else: $\frac{n}{5}\left(\frac{x-1}{5}\right)^n \to \infty$, $n \to \infty$